# How to restrict regex not to match few instances

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have my input file like this.

> ```
> <cite.query manual-edit="true" w-normalized-cite="ga48-5-48.1(a)" w-pub-number="sttx" ID="T10fe3e775fc84dbd91df107195e56833">Ga. Code Ann. § 48-5-48.1(a)</cite.query>. Any clerical error, including but not limited to, a typographical error, scrivener’s error, or any unintentional immaterial error or omission in the application will not be construed as a failure to file properly. Any document required to be filed under <srclink>Ga. Code Ann. § 48-5-48.1</srclink>
> ```

When i am trying to match `Ga. Code Ann. § 48-5-48.1`, it is matching the one present in `<cite.query` tag, which should not happen.

I should only match those patterns which are not inside cite.query tag.

How can i do that ? Please help

---

Edit from comment:

This is the regular expression iam using to match the pattern.:

```
my_regex = r'(Ga\.\s+Code\s+Ann\.\s+(?:\u00A7\s*)?[-a-z\d]+\.?[0-9]*)'
```

My code:

```
import re 
unique_list = re.findall(my_regex, temp_content)
```

my_regex will be containing the above pattern and temp_content will be contaning the input file content.

Comment: Perhaps you can check for ">Ga. Code Ann. § 48-5-48.1</" which will mean they are not part of tags?

Comment: But in my input, its not always mandatory that Ga. Code Ann. § 48-5-48.1 is present inside a srclink tag. Sometimes it is present as a normal text.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not the best way to parse html, you should use a library like `beautifulsoup`.

That said, using a [negative lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) will achieve what you want:

```
import re 

temp_content = u'<cite.query manual-edit="true" w-normalized-cite="ga48-5-48.1(a)" w-pub-number="sttx" ID="T10fe3e775fc84dbd91df107195e56833">Ga. Code Ann. § 48-5-48.1(a)</cite.query>. Any clerical error, including but not limited to, a typographical error, scrivener’s error, or any unintentional immaterial error or omission in the application will not be construed as a failure to file properly. Any document required to be filed under <srclink>Ga. Code Ann. § 48-5-48.1</srclink>'

my_regex = re.compile('Ga\.\s+Code\s+Ann\.\s+'
                      + '(?:§\s*)?'                #(?:\u00A7\s*)?
                      + '[-a-z\d]+\.?[0-9]*'
                      + '(?![^<]*<\/cite\.query)') #Negative lookahead for closing tag

print re.findall(my_regex, temp_content)

>>>[u'Ga. Code Ann. \xc2\xa7 48-5-48.1']
```